# Programmatically set button sizes depending on the size of the phone

Tags: android, xamarin

I create most of my buttons programmatically. Is there a formula or way to size my buttons according to the size of the phone? I have noticed if I create a button in the UI and I make it say height 10. It looks more or less the same on a small phone or a big phone, but if I create this button programmatically and make its height 10 I noticed it wont resize for a bigger phone. In other words it will look great on the smaller phone but terrible on the smaller phone. 
Is there a proper way to do this? Please see a simple example below

```
 LinearLayout ln = new LinearLayout (this); 
 Button btn = new Button (this);
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams Lparamters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParam    (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 10);
 ln.AddView (btn, Lparamters);
```

Comment: How do you create it now? Show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the width/height of the screen like this:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Then you can use this to assign a specific width to your buttons.

```
//First: add your button to your LinearLayout (IMPORTANT Step)
//Then: get the LayoutParams of your button
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = btn.getLayoutParams();
//Then: change the width of the button
params.width = width/2; //or whatever relative size you want.
//Then set the modefied LayoutParams to your button.
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html). define your layouts in xml!

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

put your button sizes which is fits to the Display Sizes

Answer (score 0):

You can get width and height using the `WindowManager`:

```
int width = mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

Once you get this width in your onCreate or whatever, you can use it to do stuff like:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.icon).setPadding(width/80, width/80, width/80, width/80);         
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.findViewById(R.id.icon).getLayoutParams()).setMargins(width/80, width/80, width/80, width/80);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer this but it might help someone else.

Create a button programmatically and run on a device. 
After that get the density of the device that your desired size is appearing.
Then, for other devices use this formula.

```
 float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        Log.e("TEMP", "density: " + density);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((450 / desired_size_phone_density) * desired_size_phone_density, (320/desired_size_phone_density) * density);
```

then set the Layout params to your button
`button.setLayoutParams(params)`